# Parallelize resolution of differential equation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, parallel-processing, differential-equations

i am solving a system of ordinary differential equations using the [odeint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) function. Is it possible (and if yes how) to parallelize easily this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is wrong, solving a ODE nummerically needs to calculate the function f(t,y)=y' several times per iteration, e.g. four times for Runge-Kutta. But i dont know any package for python doing this.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are saying that static_rtti's answer is incorrect and that, since f(t,y)=y' is calculated several times per iteration, one can parallelize solving the ODE on a per step basis (by having 4 processors for instance which each calculate a f(t,y)=y'). However, in the Runge-Kutta algorithm, each f(t,y)=y' that we solve for is dependent on the previous y' that has been calculated (to find the y that we use in f(t,y)) and is therefore serial.

Answer (score 1):

Numerically integrating an ODE is an intrinsically sequential operation, since you need each result to compute the following one (well, except if you're integrating from multiple starting points). So I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Wow, I've just realised this question is more than 3 years old. I'll still leave my answer hoping it finds its way to someone in the same predicament. Sorry for that.

I had the same problem. I was able to parallelise such process as follows.

First you need [dispy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net). In there you'll find some programs that will do the paralelization process for you. I am not an expert on `dispy`but I had no problems using it, and I didn't need to configure anything.

So, how to use it?

1. Run `python dispynode.py -d`. If you do not run this script before running your main program, the parallel jobs won't be performed.
2. Run your main program. Here I post the one I used (sorry for the mess). You'll need to change the function `sim`, and change accordingly to what you want to do with the results. I hope however that my program works as a reference for you.

   ```
   import os, sys, inspect

   #Add dispy to your path
   cmd_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))
   if cmd_folder not in sys.path:
       sys.path.insert(0, cmd_folder)

   # use this if you want to include modules from a subforder
   cmd_subfolder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.split(inspect.getfile( inspect.currentframe() ))[0],cmd_folder+"/dispy-3.10/")))
   if cmd_subfolder not in sys.path:
       sys.path.insert(0, cmd_subfolder)
   #----------------------------------------#
   #This function contains the differential equation to be simulated.    
   def sim(ic,e,O): #ic=initial conditions; e=Epsiolon; O=Omega 
       from scipy.integrate import ode
       import numpy as np

       #Diff Eq.
       def sys(t,x,e,O,z,b,l):
           p = 2.*e*O*np.sin(O*t)*(1-e*np.cos(O*t))/(z+(1-e*np.cos(O*t))**2)
           q = (1+4.*b/l*np.cos(O*t))*(z+(1-e*np.cos(O*t)))/( z+(1-e*np.cos(O*t))**2 )
           dx=np.zeros(2)
           dx[0] = x[1]
           dx[1] = -q*x[0]-p*x[1]
           return dx
       #Simulation.    
       t0=0; tEnd=10000.; dt=0.1
       r = ode(sys).set_integrator('dop853', nsteps=10,max_step=dt) #Definition of the integrator
       Y=[];S=[];T=[]
       # - parameters - # 
       z=0.5; l=1.0; b=0.06;
       # -------------- #
       color=1
       r.set_initial_value(ic, t0).set_f_params(e,O,z,b,l) #Set the parameters, the initial condition and the initial time
       #Loop to integrate.
       while r.successful() and r.t +dt < tEnd:
           r.integrate(r.t+dt)
           Y.append(r.y)
           T.append(r.t)
           if r.y[0]>1.25*ic[0]: #Bound. This is due to my own requirements.
               color=0
               break
           #r.y contains the solutions and r.t contains the time vector.
       return e,O,color #For each pair e,O return e,O and a color (0,1) which correspond to the color of the point in the stability chart (0=unstable) (1=stable)
       # ------------------------------------ #

   #MAIN PROGRAM where the parallel magic happens
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import dispy
   import numpy as np
   F=100 #Total files
   #Range of the values of Epsilon and Omega
   Epsilon = np.linspace(0,1,100)
   Omega_intervals   = np.linspace(0,4,F)

   ic=[0.1,0]

   cluster = dispy.JobCluster(sim) #This function sets that the cluster (array of processors) will be assigned the job sim.
   jobs = [] #Initialize the array of jobs

   for i in range(F-1):
       Data_Array=[]
       jobs = []
       Omega=np.linspace(Omega_intervals[i], Omega_intervals[i+1],10)
       print Omega
       for e in Epsilon:
           for O in Omega:
               job = cluster.submit(ic,e,O) #Send to the cluster a job with the specified parameters
               jobs.append(job) #Join all the jobs specified above
           cluster.wait()
       #Do the jobs
       for job in jobs:
           e,O,color = job()
           Data_Array.append([e,O,color])

       #Save the results of the simulation.
       file_name='Data'+str(i)+'.txt'
       f=open(file_name, 'a')
       f.write(str(Data_Array))
       f.close()
   ```